# Problems while installing Fedora 19

Tags: fedora, system-installation

Currently I have Windows 7 installed in my machine with a 500GB hard disk.

C(52 GB) drive has the windows7 installed.

D Drive contains files which I do not wish to install.

There is 52 GB of unallocated memory.

I want to replace the C drive and use that partition along with the 52 GB of unallocated memory and install Fedora 19 there.

These are the steps that I've followed.

1. Boot from DVD.
2. Install to Hard Drive.
3. Selected English as language
4. Installation Destination by default has `Automatic partitioning
   selected`. I clicked on it and it redirects to *Installation
   Destination* page.
5. Click on Reclaim Space
6. Select C drive, click on delete click on reclaim.
7. Then I get this error `Error checking storage configuration. Click for details`. After I click on it, I get the following details:

> you have not created a bootloader stage1 target device
>
> sda5 must have one of the following disklabel types: gpt.

1. I then go to custom layout
2. Add mount point `/` 30 gb `ext4`
3. Add mount point `/boot` 2 gb `ext4`
4. Add mount point `swap` 6gb `swap`
5. Add mount point `/home` 65.99 gb `ext4`
6. Click on `Done -> Accept Changes`

Then I get the following error

> you have not created a bootloader stage1 target device
>
> sda2 must have one of the following disklabel types: gpt.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Switch your system to BIOS mode boot or else create a GPT partition table (gparted or gdisk).